# SQL Server 2008: reorder group by an id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a sequence of numbers (1 to n) to a column grouped by the ID column. For example, I have a this data set:

```
ID      Name    Description Order
---------------------------------
11049   Sanchez A           5
11049   Sanchez B           4
11049   Sanchez C           5
11049   Sanchez D           7
11049   Sanchez E           6
11049   Sanchez F           2
11049   Sanchez G           1
11049   Sanchez H           3
46947   Mendez  I           1
46947   Mendez  J           1
46947   Mendez  K           2
```

Notice for the rows with an ID of `11049`, there are two 5s in the Order column. Also for the rows with an ID of `46947`, there are two 1s in the Order column. I need to make sure that there are only distinct numbers for each ID set. An example would be, for the rows with an ID of `46947`, the row with the description value of `I`, should have a column Order value of 1. The column description with value `J`, should have 2. The column description with value `K`, should have a column Order value of 3. The resulting table should look similar to  this:

```
ID      Name    Description Order
---------------------------------
11049   Sanchez A           1
11049   Sanchez B           2
11049   Sanchez C           3
11049   Sanchez D           4
11049   Sanchez E           5
11049   Sanchez F           6
11049   Sanchez G           7
11049   Sanchez H           8
46947   Mendez  I           1
46947   Mendez  J           2
46947   Mendez  K           3
```

The order in which the numbers are sequenced is not important, but I just need to make sure that there is a distinct number for each set of IDs starting with the number 1.

I thought about how to do this with T-SQL, but I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Have you looked into `ROW_NUMBER()`? Specially with a `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your data, seems you need `row_number()` function :

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by [Description]) as [order]
from table t;
```